# How I can sort a list of list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of lists, example:

```
List<List<String>> listOflists = new ArrayList();
List<String> b = {"x", "x"};
List<String> a = {"x"};
List<String> c = {"x", "x", "x"};

listOflists.add(a);
listOflists.add(b);
listOflists.add(c);

//Oder by size of the array
List<String> sortedList = listOflists.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I expected that listOflists  in a forEach process:

Lopp 1 x
Lopp 2 x,x
Lopp 3 x,x,x

Comment: Just curious: where is the string `Lopp 1` coming from?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: If your goal is to sort them based on list size then you can specify that in `sorted` method by providing Comparator which will do that like `sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size))`. But what is confusing is return type of `sortedList`. Should it be `List<List<String>> sortedList` instead of `List<String> sortedList`?

Comment: Your question needs more detail.  Your expected output isn't sufficient.  Exactly what are your sorting requirements?  Number of elements, lexical rank of each element, what to do if two lists have same number and/or types of elements. etc?  You need to be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrays.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(T%5B%5D,T%5B%5D)) compares two Object arrays, within comparable elements, lexicographically.

Try this.

```
List<List<String>> listOflists = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("x", "x"),
    Arrays.asList("x"),
    Arrays.asList("x", "x", "x")
);

List<List<String>> sortedList = listOflists.stream()
    .map(list -> list.toArray(String[]::new))
    .sorted((x, y) -> Arrays.compare(x, y))
    .map(array -> Arrays.asList(array))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(sortedList);
```

output:

```
[[x], [x, x], [x, x, x]]
```

If you want to sort by list size.

```
List<List<String>> sortedList = listOflists.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(list -> list.size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wow! `Arrays.compare` is a really nice feature :)